# ffmpeg desktop stream to m3u8

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, http-live-streaming, m3u8

banging my head against the wall!
What I want, stream my Desktop with FFmpeg to web site.

My setup is windows 10 Pro + apache + ffmpeg

C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-3.4.1-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -offset_x 10 -offset_y 20 -video_size 800x600 -show_region 1 -i desktop  -s 800x600 -c:v libx264 -b:v 800000 -segment_time 3 -start_number 1 "mystream.m3u8"

what is not working the multisection ".ts" file are not limited by the -segment_time 3 and I tried: -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 2
Don´t know if this is Apple related or so.
Looking at the FFmpeg docs and help file does not work for me.
Please, do you have any advice what command syntax to limit the .ts file amount.

Many thanks, 5inch

Comment: Remove `-segment_time 3` and add `-g 30 -hls_time 3`

Comment: Hi Gyan, many thanks for your support. You mean like this: "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-3.4.1-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -offset_x 10 -offset_y 20 -video_size 800x600 -show_region 1 -i desktop  -s 800x600 -c:v libx264 -b:v 800000 -g 30 -hls_time 3 -start_number 1 "mystream.m3u8"

Comment: but i still get more than 3 ts files. is so strange...

Comment: maybe not well explained from my side. I want when it loops to 3.ts ffmpeg starts at 1.ts and overwrites the files.

Comment: Add `-hls_wrap 3`

Comment: Hi Gyan, you ROCK! Looks good. did not find this attribute. Is not listet through --help and did not find in the Docs. Any tip or link where I can find it. Many thanks!

Comment: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2

Comment: oh. I knew I missed some functions. So good. Many thanks! Great Support!

Comment: looks good. do you have a tip what streaming type works best in browser like chrome and firefox?

Comment: cannot get the stream visible in firefox... did not know that streaming is that hard in a webbrowser. what is youtube using then...

Comment: HLS cannot be directly played in the browser, except for Safari. You need a player like hls.js. Look for an extension.

Comment: Hi Gyan, right. Any other streaming format like mp4 or webm which can been used without an extension? I m playing arround with mp4 and webm but does not work. Many thanks for your tips.